# MySQL error: #1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in

Tags: mysql, sql

Tras realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT CP.code
FROM cart_products AS CP
    INNER JOIN products AS P
        ON P.code = CP.code
WHERE CP.cartID = 22207
    AND (P.stock - CP.quantity) > 0
```

Obtuve el siguiente error:

> #1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in (`DB_NAME`.`p`.`stock` - `DB_NAME`.`cp`.`quantity`)'

La estructura de las tablas es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `productID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `code` tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `stock` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `cart_products` (
  `cartID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `code` tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

¿Como puedo hacer la consulta sin obtener este error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error sucede porque se espera que el cálculo entre 2 enteros sin signo también produzca un número entero sin signo.  Pero si el cálculo puede resultar en un número negativo (que es tu caso), obviamente, esto no es válido.

Una solución es el `CAST` que mencionas en tu respuesta.

Pero más sencillo sería de usar la condición equivalente siguiente para evitar el cálculo y el riesgo de un número negativo:

```
AND P.stock > CP.quantity
```

Answer (score 2):

El error es causado por un "*desbordamiento de entero sin signo*"

La solución que encontré fue convertir ([`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)) los enteros sin signo (`eg: UNSIGNED`) a con signo (`eg: SIGNED`)

### Solución:

```
SELECT CP.code
FROM cart_products AS CP
    INNER JOIN products AS P
        ON P.code = CP.code
WHERE CP.cartID = 22207
    AND (CAST(P.stock AS SIGNED) - CAST(CP.quantity AS SIGNED)) > 0
```